# Use an object sent in as a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, filehelpers

I have a method which receives a generic type

```
public string GetObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
     //Type t = typeof(T);
     //Type t = obj.GetType();
     //var t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),new object[] {obj });
     var output = fh.WriteString(t);
     return output;
}
```

I want to access this object received in as a generic type so I can use it as a parameter to the [`FileHelperEngine`](http://www.filehelpers.net/)'s `WriteString` method. None of the commented lines above are working where in if I attempt to use the `t` variable generated from either of the methods in the first three commented lines, I get an error saying

> Argument System.Type is not assignable to parameter type
>   `Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`

How do I get the object to be used in the `WriteString` method?

**EDIT**
My apologies if I appeared vague :) I actually want the value passed in to the method to be used by the FileHelperEngine. I am not sure if any of the commented lines are correct or the ideal way to go about getting the actual object sent in to a generic type. All I want is to be able to send the value received in the paramter as obj be consumed by the FileHelperEngine, which is basically send this IEnumerable obj to the WriteString method.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear. [The method signature accepts a `IEnumerable<T>`](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1_WriteString_1.htm), not a `Type` object. You need to pass the `IEnumerable<T>` *instance*:

```
public string GetObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
     return fh.WriteString(obj);
}
```

**Edit:**

After looking around in the `FileEngineHelper` class, I'm going to assume you used the non generic `FileEngineHelper` constructor which accepts a `Type` object instead of the generic class constructor. When you use the non-generic class constructor, `WriteString` will always take an `IEnumerable<object>`, and not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Moving to the generic version, this works:

```
public class F<T> where T : class
{
    private FileHelperEngine<T> fh = new FileHelperEngine<T>();
    public string GetObject(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        return fh.WriteString(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: But again, see OP's code. It seems like OP isn't trying to give `obj`, but the instance created using reflection, where the whole `T` type has a one parameter constructor accepting the whole `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I think the OP is confused :) That's exactly my point.

Comment: Well, I've dropped my answer as it seems like yours is the right one. BTW, I don't understand why OP hasn't tried to give `obj` to `WriteString` directly and see what happens.......

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I don't understand either :P

Comment: Sometimes I feel people think that writing a line of code may produce an atomic explosion that would eat the universe, while pressing the "Build solution" or "Build" option can just give you the hint to move on and avoid wasting your time asking useless questions :D

Comment: using obj directly I get this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> ` and this one as well `The best overloaded method match for 'FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<T>.WriteString(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: using that "hint" I tried the commented lines which of course did not work and so I am here trying to find my way from someone who knows more than I do. :)

Comment: @user20358 I'm not sure if solving a conversion is enough to ask a question anyway

Comment: @user20358 What `Type` object did you pass to the `FileHelperEngine` class constructor? In your error message, you cannot convert from `IEnumerable<T>` to what?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer then what is?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I did not pass any class to the `FileHelperEngine`'s constructor. If I replace that `T` with any standard poco object right there it works. Its just that I am not sure how to make the `WriteString` method understand how to deal with a generic type. and you are right I am confused about it and hence this post on SO :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is what I see being used for the file helper `FileHelperEngine<T> fh = new FileHelperEngine<T>();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92632/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-user20358).

Comment: The actual error that I see is as follows: Argument type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` not assignable to parameter type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> [mscorlib, version=4.0.0.....`

Comment: @user20358 Click on the chat link, lets continue there.

Comment: Was this resolved? It almost sounds like generic T was being confused between object and the actual type so I'm curious as to the resolution since the last edit and comment time are within (currently) 23 hours ago.

Comment: Was it as above or did you have to do something different?

Comment: @netniV OP had both a class generic parameter `T` *and* a method argumet generic parameter. That was causing the problem